# Prevent Chrome from force scrolling cursor into view

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

We're working on a text editor (based on a textarea) that moves the 'canvas' to the right to reveal a menu on the left. Pretty much the standard slide-to-show-menu.

The menu is a list of documents, and when you click on one, the textarea is filled with the selected document text and the cursor is set to the last saved position via selectionRange/Range.

Here it gets funky: Part of the textarea is off the right side of the screen, and if the cursor is placed there (or even near there), Chrome scrolls the canvas div into the the left despite position:relative.

Is there any way to prevent this?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="canvas>
        <textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 left: 300px; /* set via js, to show the menu */
 right: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
 position: relative;
 width: 1440px; /* viewport width set via js */
}

textarea {
 width: 100%; /* this properly relates to the fixed width canvas parent */
}
```

Comment: There's no real way to prevent scrolling other than removing the scrollbars.

Comment: Isn't setting position fixed for `#canvas` an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this would screw up a lot of other stuff like vertical scrolling if the document is longer than the viewport height etc. Good thinking though.

Comment: Can you show a demo? I just can't visualize what the issue is.

Comment: Why move the canvas/textarea off to the side to reveal the menu when you could set the menu to show overtop and have that slide *into* view?

Comment: Hi all, thanks a ton for all your comments & revisited this, please see potential answer below and solution at https://www.hiroapp.com/backdoor

Answer (score 1):

OP here: This seems to be unpreventable. The problem is that if the cursor position is in an overflown part of `inner-editor` Shadow DOM element, and thus invisible, Chrome will move the `inner-editor` (= the textarea content) around until the cursor is positioned in whatever part of the textarea is visible.

Afaik as this is part of the shadow DOM, it's pretty hard to change this behavior without replacing the default textarea with your own Web Component.

In our case this problem was partially clouded as the `textarea` content in question consisted of a long change of white-space characters, which didn't get wrapped but weren't visible either.

The solution we applied are scrollhandlers that return everything to it's intended position right after the browser moves it around.